# Roundup function in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a requirement as below

```
121.36
121.025
121.1
121.000
```

Desired output

```
122
122
122
121
```

Command used

```
awk -F"." '{if($8>0){print $11}}'
```

Comment: so everything not being `.000` gets rounded up?

Comment: If a value after decimal is greater than 0 then it will add +1 else leave a it i.

Answer (score 8):

What you're asking for is a `ceil()` (for "[ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)") function. It's important to include zero and negative numbers in your example when you're looking for any kind of rounding function as it's easy to get them wrong so using this input file:

```
$ cat file
1.999999
1.0
0.000001
0
-0.000001
-1.0
-1.999999
```

we can test a `ceil()` function:

```
$ awk 'function ceil(x, y){y=int(x); return(x>y?y+1:y)} {print $0,ceil($0)}' file
1.999999 2
1.0 1
0.000001 1
0 0
-0.000001 0
-1.0 -1
-1.999999 -1
```

and the opposite `floor()` function:

```
$ awk 'function floor(x, y){y=int(x); return(x<y?y-1:y)} {print $0,floor($0)}' file
1.999999 1
1.0 1
0.000001 0
0 0
-0.000001 -1
-1.0 -1
-1.999999 -2
```

The above works because `int()` truncates towards zero (from the GNU awk manual):

```
int(x)
    Return the nearest integer to x, located between x and zero and
    truncated toward zero. For example, int(3) is 3, int(3.9) is 3,
    int(-3.9) is -3, and int(-3) is -3 as well.
```

so `int()` of a negative number already does what you want for a ceiling function, i.e. round up, and you just have to add 1 to the result if `int()` rounded down a positive number.

I used `0.000001`, etc. in the samples to avoid people getting a false positive testing a solution that adds some number like `0.9` and then `int()`ing.

Also note that `ceil()` could be abbreviated to:

```
function ceil(x){return int(x)+(x>int(x))}
```

but I wrote it as above for clarity (it's not clear/obvious that the result of `x>int(x)` is 1 or 0) and efficiency (only call `int()` once instead of twice).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a way to do this in plain bash, but since bash can only do integer arithmetic I failed. You do need another language to work with you here.

I would write a shell function as a wrapper around that other langugage. For example:

```
$ ceil() { perl -MPOSIX=ceil -lpe '$_ = ceil($_)'; }

$ ceil <<END
121.36
121.025
121.1
121.000
0.1
0
-0.1
-3.0
-3.1
END
```

outputs

```
122
122
122
121
1
0
0
-3
-3
```

Any other language will do: `ceil() { ruby -ne 'puts $_.to_f.ceil'; }`

Comment: Or, for completeness, `ceil() { awk '{print int($0)+($0>int($0))}'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Or, without the use of a condition,

```
function ceil(x) { return int(x + (1 - 1e-15)); }
```

The performance difference here is negligible, but it is a method I like keeping in mind for cases where it isn't.

The choice of `15` in `1e-15` arises from double-precision floating point which has 16 significant digits, so we're adding `0.99...` with 16 nines. This way `1` doesn't get to `2` but `1.0...01` with 14 zeros does get rounded up.

---

*Testing code*

```
echo 3 18 | awk '
    function ceil_old(x, y){ y=int(x); return(x>y?y+1:y) } 
    function ceil(x) { return int(x + (1 - 1e-15)); }
    { 
        x = $1; 
        n = $2; 
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i) { 
            y = 10 ** -i;
            z = ceil(x+y);
            w = ceil_old(x+y);
            if (z != w) {
                print x" + 1e-"i " = " x+y " -> " z " <=> " w; 
                exit 1; 
            }
            z = ceil(x-y); 
            w = ceil_old(x-y);
            if (z != w) {
                print x" - 1e-"i " = " x-y " -> " z " <=> " w;
                exit 1;
            }
        }
    }
'
```

Change `1e-15` to `1e-16` or `1e-10` to see how this affects behavior.